# Session timeout when browser is closed (vaadin)

Tags: java, session, vaadin, vaadin7

I have a spring-boot application with an embedded tomcat and vaadin 7.5.3. I set the session timeout to 60 seconds. The heartbeat interval is 5 seconds and the "closeIdleSessions" parameter is true.

I experienced that the session was destroyed after 60-70 seconds when the browser was opened and the user was inactive, but if i closed the browser, the session was destroyed only after 2-2.5 minutes.

Does the browser's opened-closed state make any change on the session timeout?

EDIT:

I experienced if i turn off vaadin push then everything is ok, so i think this is a push-related problem.